# Flash ComboBox Component customisation

Tags: flash, combobox, components

Is there anyway to change the colour of items showing in the dropdown list?  By default, it's showing skyblue and I need to change it into grey? I'm using Flash CS4 IDE and AS3.  any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the combo box component: the combo box skin and the actual >item cells.

The combo box can be edited by placing an instance of the component on the stage in the CS4 IDE, and then double clicking it to edit the individual button states (check the downSkin).

Once you have an instance on the stage, look in the Library. You will now have a few folders and files from the component. The skinning of the cell can be found in 'Component Assets' and then in the 'CellRendererSkins' folder. You can edit these in the same way.

To alter the blue colour you will need to change:

- CellRenderer_selectedUpSkin
- CellRenderer_selectedDownSkin
- CellRenderer_overSkin
- CellRenderer_downSkin

An alternative would be to look at creating a CSSStyleDeclaration and then apply that using AS3. This is useful if you want all your components to look the same.